# How to use another pretrained BERT model with the ktrain text classifier?

Tags: python, bert-language-model, ktrain

How can we use a different pretrained model for the text classifier in the ktrain library? When using:

> model = text.text_classifier('bert', (x_train, y_train) ,
> preproc=preproc)

[This uses the multilangual pretrained model](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/multilingual.md)

However, I want to try out a monolingual model as well. Namely the Dutch one: ''wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased', which is also used in other k-train implementations, [for example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/CoNLL2002_Dutch-BiLSTM.ipynb).

However, when trying to use this command in the text classifier it does not work:

```
model = text.text_classifier('bert', (x_train, y_train) ,
> preproc=preproc, bert_model='wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased')
```

or

```
model = text.text_classifier('wietsedv/bert-base-dutch-cased', (x_train, y_train), preproc=preproc)
```

Does anyone how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two text classification APIs in **ktrain**.  The first is the `text_classifier` API which can be used for a select number of both transformers and non-transformers models.  The second is the `Transformer` API which can be used with any `transformers` model including the one you listed.

The latter is explained in detail in [this tutorial notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-A3-hugging_face_transformers.ipynb) and [this medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-hugging-face-transformers-in-tensorflow-2-without-tears-ee50e4f3e7ed?gi=77820bfc9da6).

For instance, you can replace `MODEL_NAME` with any model you want in the example below:

Example:

```py
# load text data
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian','comp.graphics', 'sci.med']
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
train_b = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True)
test_b = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',categories=categories, shuffle=True)
(x_train, y_train) = (train_b.data, train_b.target)
(x_test, y_test) = (test_b.data, test_b.target)

# build, train, and validate model (Transformer is wrapper around transformers library)
import ktrain
from ktrain import text
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'  # replace this with model of choice
t = text.Transformer(MODEL_NAME, maxlen=500, class_names=train_b.target_names)
trn = t.preprocess_train(x_train, y_train)
val = t.preprocess_test(x_test, y_test)
model = t.get_classifier()
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=trn, val_data=val, batch_size=6)
learner.fit_onecycle(5e-5, 4)
learner.validate(class_names=t.get_classes()) # class_names must be string values

# Output from learner.validate()
#                        precision    recall  f1-score   support
#
#           alt.atheism       0.92      0.93      0.93       319
#         comp.graphics       0.97      0.97      0.97       389
#               sci.med       0.97      0.95      0.96       396
#soc.religion.christian       0.96      0.96      0.96       398
#
#              accuracy                           0.96      1502
#             macro avg       0.95      0.96      0.95      1502
#          weighted avg       0.96      0.96      0.96      1502
```